# MVC 5 dropdown list for selecting an item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding an MVC5 internet application, and am getting an error when trying to display a dropdown list for a model attribute that is populated from a ViewModel.

Here is my Create ActionResult:

```
List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> blobs = new List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
foreach (var blobItem in blobContainer.ListBlobs())
{
    System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem selectListItem = new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem();
    selectListItem.Value = blobItem.Uri.ToString();
    selectListItem.Text = blobItem.Uri.ToString();
    blobs.Add(selectListItem);
}
AssetViewModel assetViewModel = new AssetViewModel();
assetViewModel.fileNames = blobs;
```

Here is my Create View code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.asset.webAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.asset.webAddress, new SelectList(Model.fileNames, "Value", "Text"), "  -----Select List-----  ")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.asset.webAddress)
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

At line:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.asset.webAddress, new SelectList(Model.fileNames, "Value", "Text"), "  -----Select List-----  ")
```

Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

```
public class AssetViewModel
{
    public Asset asset { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> fileNames { get; set; }

    public AssetViewModel(Asset asset)
    {
        this.asset = asset;
    }

    public AssetViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect The `asset` property of model is null (you dont appear to be initializing it in the code above)

Comment: Can you please share Declaration of MODEL on you VIEW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model asset property `m.asset` is null.
Looks like you want to implement something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.webAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.webAddress, new SelectList(Model.fileNames, "Value", "Text"), "  -----Select List-----  ")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.webAddress)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Simple mistake, I was not passing the ViewModel correctly to the View.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DDLFor` syntax looks differently than I have used.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LeagueId, Model.TeamSL, new { id = "ddlTeam" })
```

I'm not sure what `m.asset.WebAddress` is, that could be part of the error as others have stated.